# Check if visit has been directed with PHP Location header

Tags: php, redirect, header

I'm redirecting from page-A to page-B, like this:

```
header( 'Location: ' https://example.org/landingpath );
```

I want to detect, when landing on page-B, if I came there by above-written `header`-redirection - or if I simply refreshed my browser. How do I do that?

---

I tried adding a custom header:

```
header( 'TESTHEADER: foobar' ); // added it both before and after 'Location' to be sure.
header( 'Location: ' https://example.org/landingpath );
header( 'TESTHEADER: foobar' );
```

... But I can't see `TESTHEADER` in the dumps after the redirects (see dumps below).

**Here is `$_SERVER` and `getallheaders();` after the redirect:**

```
Array
(
    [PHPRC] => /home/MYSITE/fcgi-bin/../etc/php7.2
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    [PWD] => /home/MYSITE/fcgi-bin
    [SHLVL] => 0
    [PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS] => 99999
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 0
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /landingpath.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /landingpath
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /landingpath
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 56999
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/MYSITE/public_html/landingpath.php
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/MYSITE/public_html
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/MYSITE/public_html
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 123.123.123.123
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 111.111.111.111
    [SERVER_NAME] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at MYDOMAIN.TLD Port 443


    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.9,da;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
    [HTTP_REFERER] => https://MYDOMAIN.TLD/hard
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM] => "macOS"
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE] => ?0
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA] => " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST] => document
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER] => ?1
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE] => navigate
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE] => same-origin
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => no-cache
    [HTTP_PRAGMA] => no-cache
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_HOST] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
    [SSL_TLS_SNI] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
    [HTTPS] => on
    [SCRIPT_URI] => https://MYDOMAIN.TLD/landingpath
    [SCRIPT_URL] => /landingpath
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
    [REDIRECT_HTTPS] => on
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI] => https://MYDOMAIN.TLD/landingpath
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL] => /landingpath
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /landingpath.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1645074245.6675
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1645074245
)

Array
(
    [Content-Length] => 0
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9,da;q=0.8
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
    [Referer] => https://MYDOMAIN.TLD/hard
    [Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform] => "macOS"
    [Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile] => ?0
    [Sec-Ch-Ua] => " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
    [Sec-Fetch-Dest] => document
    [Sec-Fetch-User] => ?1
    [Sec-Fetch-Mode] => navigate
    [Sec-Fetch-Site] => same-origin
    [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36
    [Upgrade-Insecure-Requests] => 1
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [Pragma] => no-cache
    [Connection] => close
    [Host] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
)
```

**And here is `$_SERVER` and `getallheaders();` after a refresh:**

```
Array
(
    [PHPRC] => /home/MYSITE/fcgi-bin/../etc/php7.2
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    [PWD] => /home/MYSITE/fcgi-bin
    [SHLVL] => 0
    [PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS] => 99999
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 0
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /landingpath.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /landingpath
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /landingpath
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 57045
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/MYSITE/public_html/landingpath.php
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/MYSITE/public_html
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/MYSITE/public_html
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 123.123.123.123
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 111.111.111.111
    [SERVER_NAME] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at MYDOMAIN.TLD Port 443


    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.9,da;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
    [HTTP_REFERER] => https://MYDOMAIN.TLD/hard
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST] => document
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER] => ?1
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE] => navigate
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE] => same-origin
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM] => "macOS"
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE] => ?0
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA] => " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => no-cache
    [HTTP_PRAGMA] => no-cache
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_HOST] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
    [SSL_TLS_SNI] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
    [HTTPS] => on
    [SCRIPT_URI] => https://MYDOMAIN.TLD/landingpath
    [SCRIPT_URL] => /landingpath
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
    [REDIRECT_HTTPS] => on
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI] => https://MYDOMAIN.TLD/landingpath
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL] => /landingpath
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /landingpath.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1645074268.9317
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1645074268
)

Array
(
    [Content-Length] => 0
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9,da;q=0.8
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
    [Referer] => https://MYDOMAIN.TLD/hard
    [Sec-Fetch-Dest] => document
    [Sec-Fetch-User] => ?1
    [Sec-Fetch-Mode] => navigate
    [Sec-Fetch-Site] => same-origin
    [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36
    [Upgrade-Insecure-Requests] => 1
    [Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform] => "macOS"
    [Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile] => ?0
    [Sec-Ch-Ua] => " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [Pragma] => no-cache
    [Connection] => close
    [Host] => MYDOMAIN.TLD
)
```

---

### Findings

I can see that it adds these lines *after the redirect* to the headers:

```
[HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM] => "macOS"
[HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE] => ?0
[HTTP_SEC_CH_UA] => " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
```

And I can see that it adds these lines *after the refresh* to `$_SERVER:

```
[Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform] => "macOS"
[Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile] => ?0
[Sec-Ch-Ua] => " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
```

But none of which seems like 'something to listen on'.

What is the proper way to do this, when I control both page-A and page-B?

---

### Solution considerations

- I could set a cookie, but it seems quite excessive.
- I could set a session variable, but that too seems like a bit much
- I could pass a GET-request, but I'd like to not do this, if I can avoid it (since it's visible to the visitor in the URL).

Comment: Session is fine. You set in page A, do the detection in page B and unset in Page B. It is very minimal and lightweight approach.

Comment: _"But I can't see TESTHEADER in the dumps after the redirects"_ - and why should you, you are dumping _request_ headers there, but what you are issuing with `header( ...)` from your script, are _response_ headers.

Comment: I think it is common practice to use a GET request for what you're trying to do. If you really want to avoid it, then use a session or a cookie. But since you're throwing all three possible options out the door, there is not much left.